# Can't figure out transforming points -opengl for lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl, pong

I am making a pong game to up my knowledge in game programming. I'm stuck on getting to move vertexes. I made a simple cube to try and figure it out. Nothing came to mind.

Here's my code: 
package com.pong.game;

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11
public class Main {

    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
            GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

            // clear screen
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            // set color
            GL11.glColor3f(0.78f, 0.31f, 0.35f);

            // draw the quad
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100 + 200, 100);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100 + 200, 100 + 200);
            GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100 + 200);

            GL11.glEnd();

            // sync and update
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }
        Display.destroy();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main game = new Main();
        game.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want this to do, and what is it doing wrong?

Comment: I want to move a vertex to another point. Translations.